# Can we use $save as $add in firebase (angular Fire)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Can we use $save to add data rather than $add in firebase object ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for **AngularFire** implies that `$save` cant be used to do modifications such as `$add` or `$remove`.

> ### $save(recordOrIndex)
>
> The array itself cannot be modified, but records in the array can be updated and saved back to the database individually. This method saves an existing, modified local record back to the database. It accepts either an array index or a reference to an item that exists in the array.

-- [AngularFire API Reference -- $save record](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex)